# Subclass an abstract parameterized class with byte-buddy

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

I begin with byte-buddy the very impressive byte-code manipulation library. It works fine but I have a problem with subclassing an abstract, parameterized class:

```
public interface Task<DTO extends IDatabaseObject> {

  void execute(DTO input);

  Class<DTO> getDataObjectClass();
}
```

With this being the abstract class :

```
public abstract class AbstractTask<T extends IDatabaseObject> implements Task<T> {

  protected Class<T> dataObjectClass = /* Call to an external method which retrieves the class from T */;

  @Override
  public Class<T> getDataObjectClass() {
    return dataObjectClass;
  }
}
```

I want to create a concrete class extending

```
public abstract class AbstractTask<T extends IDatabaseObject> implements Task<T> {

  protected String SUCCESS_MESSAGE_PREFIX = "task.mess.";

  protected Class<T> dataObjectClass;// = Introspector.getParameterizedTypeClass(this, AbstractTask.class, 0);

  @Override
  public Class<T> getDataObjectClass() {
    return dataObjectClass;
  }

  @Override
  public String getSuccessMessage(IDatabaseObject t) {
    final String messageKey = SUCCESS_MESSAGE_PREFIX + this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    final MessagesFactory messagesFactory = MessagesFactory.getInstance();
    return messagesFactory.isPresent(messageKey) ? messagesFactory.get(messageKey) : "";
  }
}
```

I want to create a concrete class of `AbstractTask`, to fullfil the following assertion:

```
createConcreteImplementation(Person.class).getDataObjectClass() == Person.class
```

where the `createConcreteImplementation` method creates an subclass via Byte Buddy. Even if this is not possible, I welcom suggestions for alternative ways or approximative this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Byte Buddy does not fully support generic types at the moment. This is something I am currently working with (I wrote Byte Buddy) and I hope to support this feature sometime this year.

You can however always overwrite Byte Buddy to override the `getDataObjectClass` method in order to return the class from the method instead of using the field's value:

```
AbstractTask<?> createConcreteImplementation(Class<?> type)
  return new ByteBuddy()
    .subclass(AbstractTask.class)
    .method(named("getDataObjectClass"))
    .intercept(FixedValue.value(new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(type))) // (*)
    .make()
    .load(type.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
    .getLoaded();
}
```

The explicit wrapping at *1* is necessary because of a bug that will go away with the next version: https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/pull/34#issuecomment-118888979